# Ansible how to select a nested list in a attribut of list

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-facts

Hi I would like to known how I can select a list nested in an attibut of a list. I've done a research on my F5 BIG IP and it give me a list of the attibutes of the virtuals servers like that:

```
    "/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_https_virtual_server": {
        "last_hop_pool": "",
        "name": "vs_portailopal_wi_https_virtual_server",
        "nat64_state": "STATE_DISABLED",
        "object_status": {
            "availability_status": "AVAILABILITY_STATUS_RED",
            "enabled_status": "ENABLED_STATUS_DISABLED",
            "status_description": "The children pool member(s) are down"
        },
        "profile": [
            {
                "profile_context": "PROFILE_CONTEXT_TYPE_CLIENT",
                "profile_name": "/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_clientssl_profile",
                "profile_type": "PROFILE_TYPE_CLIENT_SSL"
            },
            {
                "profile_context": "PROFILE_CONTEXT_TYPE_ALL",
                "profile_name": "/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_http_profile",
                "profile_type": "PROFILE_TYPE_HTTP"
            },
            {
                "profile_context": "PROFILE_CONTEXT_TYPE_ALL",
                "profile_name": "/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_http_profile-cache",
                "profile_type": "PROFILE_TYPE_WEBACCELERATION"
            },]
        },
    },
```

So I would like to compare the name of the virtual serveur and the name of each profile. I can select the name of the vitual server but I can't enter in the list of profile to select the name because it's a nested list in an attribute

This is I doing:

```
---
- name: Search
hosts: F5
gather_facts: no
connection: local


vars:
  username: '{{ cpt_username }}'
  password: '{{ cpt_password }}'

tasks: 


  - name: Get virtual-servers
    bigip_facts:
      include:
        - virtual_server
      server: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
      user: '{{ username }}'
      password: '{{ password }}'
      validate_certs: no



  - name: filter on VIP_nommage when VIP_partition is OK
    lineinfile: 
      line: 
        - "{{ inventory_hostname }}  Virtual Server : {{ item.key }} => POOL: {{ item.value.profile.name }}" 
      dest: "xxxxx/file.csv"
      state: present
    with_dict: "{{ virtual_server }}"
```

I want to store in file all profiles name per virtual serveur and in other task filter on their names.

Comment: Welcome on SO. Maybe the docs https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-subelements help. And if you need an other version please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the bigip Ansible modules, and I definitely don't have any F5 kit to test against :) Before saying anything else, a big note is that the docs say that 'bigip_facts' is now deprecated, and you should be using 'bigip_device_facts'. But if you want to use this module, can you do a couple of things:

1) Edit your original question to add the detail you posted in your reply. It is better to keep editing your original question with additional information, rather than add answers, as it makes it easier to understand your entire situation.

2) Create a new playbook that contains:

```
---
- hosts: F5
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  vars:
    username: '{{ cpt_username }}'
    password: '{{ cpt_password }}'

  tasks: 
    - name: Get virtual-servers
      bigip_facts:
        include:
          - virtual_server
        server: '{{ inventory_hostname }}'
        user: '{{ username }}'
        password: '{{ password }}'
        validate_certs: no
      register: bigip_facts_data

    - name: Display collected data
      debug:
        var: bigip_facts_data
```

This will show us the data that Ansible is actually working with. Paste the output into your original reply, in place the of the JSON that you originally pasted. It may look like this:

```
"/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_https_virtual_server":
  last_hop_pool: ''
  name: vs_portailopal_wi_https_virtual_server
  nat64_state: STATE_DISABLED
  object_status:
    availability_status: AVAILABILITY_STATUS_RED
    enabled_status: ENABLED_STATUS_DISABLED
    status_description: The children pool member(s) are down
  profile:
  - profile_context: PROFILE_CONTEXT_TYPE_CLIENT
    profile_name: "/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_clientssl_profile"
    profile_type: PROFILE_TYPE_CLIENT_SSL
  - profile_context: PROFILE_CONTEXT_TYPE_ALL
    profile_name: "/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_http_profile"
    profile_type: PROFILE_TYPE_HTTP
  - profile_context: PROFILE_CONTEXT_TYPE_ALL
    profile_name: "/Common/vs_portailopal_wi_http_profile-cache"
    profile_type: PROFILE_TYPE_WEBACCELERATION
```

If it does, then this may produce the output you need (tho I am still not clear I fully understand what you require - hopefully we are closer):

```
 - name: filter on VIP_nommage when VIP_partition is OK
    lineinfile: 
      line: 
        - "{{ inventory_hostname }}  Virtual Server : {{ item.0.name }} => POOL: {{ item.1.profile_name }}" 
      dest: "xxxxx/file.csv"
      state: present
    with_subelements:
      - "{{ bigip_fact_data }}"
      - profile
```

Really, 'with_subelements' is deprecated now along with the other 'with_' constructs, but if you are using 'bigip_facts' I guess you are using an older version of Ansible.

Comment: Thanks you for your response:

Comment: I have replaced my answer based on your additional information.

Comment: Thanks to you it's exactly I want to do